# Size of the bullet using \itemize

Tags: environments, fontsize, itemize

I was wondering what is the (standard) size of the bullets that appear using the `itemize` environment:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item ABC
\end{itemize}
```

Is it `\small`, `\tiny`...?

Is there any way to know what is the standard sizes used under the different environments in LaTeX?

Comment: The symbol is `\textbullet` in the same size as the current font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `itemize` label (on first level) is defined in `\labelitemi` which is for `article` and `book` or `report` a placeholder for `\textbullet`.

The following code loops through the various standard font size declaration commands and shows, that unless other settings are done, the label bullet is typeset with `\normalsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \foreach \x in {tiny,small,normalsize,large,Large, LARGE, huge} {%
  \item \csname \x\endcsname \labelitemi \textbackslash\x: 
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've omitted the `\footnotesize` declaration since this isn't used very often in the text body

Comment: I would advise to add `\scriptsize` because this will give a bullet in the same size as `\textbullet` while using package `lmodern`.

Comment: Is it recommended to use `\normalsize` for the bullets?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing was changed, it is `\normalsize`. Take $\bullet$ to compare.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
The same size: $\bullet$.
\end{itemize}

{\large
\begin{itemize}
\item
The same size: $\bullet$.
\end{itemize}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explain better? Or show a MWE?

Comment: Is it recommended to use `\normalsize` for bullets?